# Firebase Query retrieving info 3 levels deep

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Below is the my query.**

- Attached is a picture of my database.
- I'm trying to return what is in blue but I keep getting what is in red.

  ```
      Query userInterestQuery = mReference
          .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_interest_post));
        //.equalTo(getItem(position).getPhoto_id());
  userInterestQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

              Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user this: interest "  + singleSnapshot.getValue(NewPost.class).getInterest());
              Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user this: Caption "  + singleSnapshot.getValue(NewPost.class).getCaption());
              holder.interest.setText(singleSnapshot.getValue(NewPost.class).getInterest());
              holder.caption.setText(singleSnapshot.getValue(NewPost.class).getInterest());

          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
  });
  ```

  **Here is a pic of my database**

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: What are the values of `mReference` and `R.string.dbname_user_interest_post`?

Comment: `mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` is just referencing the database. `R.string.db_user_interest_post` is the name of the database node saved as a string.

Comment: `R.string.db_user_interest_post` is the name of the database which has the value of what?

Comment: if you look at the attached picture`R.string.db_user_interest_post` is user_interest_post. Its used to signify what node of the database I want to look in.

Comment: One more question, why do ou have that pushed id and the interest field at same level? Is this really what you want?

Comment: Well, not sure. The idea is to eventually make a query that compares interest that the user has selected to other users and then displays only the post that share common interest.

Comment: So do you want to keep that property in the future. Usually, in a node you should keep objects of the same type. You have a pushed id that contains an object and a property.

Comment: I can create a separate node for the interest and make this node only show users and post. Is this what you suggest?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And then you want to get the `interest` property of a single (logged in) user or of all users within `user_interest_post` node?

Comment: All the users in the node. I have it displaying the user profile pic, user name, and date it was created. Still need to grab the interest, caption and image_path. Everything works except for these three items. I figured if I get the interest ill be able to grab everything else I need as well.

Comment: I cannot see under that pushed id any `profile pic` or `user name` properties. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I am getting that info from another node.

Comment: I'm affraid that you did not explained the entire situation.

Comment: Whoops, I did however fix my issue. i was already getting the info and only needed to set it to my list adapter.